# self.revealViewController object null after logout

Tags: ios

I have implemented project where i have used `SWRevealViewController` and it is working fine but when i logged out using below code

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            LoginViewController *loginView = \[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"\];

            UINavigationController *navController = \[\[UINavigationController alloc\] initWithRootViewController:loginView\];

            \[UIApplication sharedApplication\].delegate.window.rootViewController = navController;

        });
```

its logout successfully but when i logged in again using below code

```
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UIStoryboard *storyboard = \[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil\];
            DashboardViewController *dashboardView = \[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DashboardViewController"\];
            \[self.navigationController pushViewController:dashboardView animated:YES\];
        });
```

its login but side menu button not working because `self.revealViewController` object getting "`null`".
can anybody help me to resolve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, your rootViewController always has to be the revealViewController.  If you reset it to be something else then you won't get the revealController behavior.

You will have to set it back to the revealController if you want to get the functionality back.  Go back and see how you set up the revealController and recreate that in your login methods.